How to enable HDR support in Windows 11 when specs are sufficient?
On a new laptop computer, Windows 11 is reporting, in its Display capabilities section of Settings > System > Display > HDR:
Display capabilities

   HDR video streaming   Supported
   Use HDR               Not supported

The laptop has a 300nit, 100% DCI-P3, 2560x1600 screen and an Intel Core i7-13650HX CPU.  The CPU has Intel's integrated graphics, and the laptop also has a discrete NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 GPU.
It seems like all the specs are more than sufficient for HDR support.
Windows and drivers have been updated.
How can HDR support be enabled?  (Or if it can't, why not?)
